# Why do we need Event handling of Spring framework? Where is it used in real world scenarios?

Tags: spring

I was going through spring tutorial and came across : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/event_handling_in_spring.htm

These events include: ContextRefreshedEvent, ContextStartedEvent, ContextStoppedEvent, ContextClosedEvent, RequestHandledEvent.

So wondering when should I use these events of Spring actually in a project.
What should be the possible use of executing an event on context getting started or closed etc. Tutorial link above only tells how to implement these events, I would like to know "why" implement such events related to Context of Spring.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming

Comment: I wanted to know where these are used in real world scenarios. Better if someoe can list out few scenarios of need of using it in an application. Question with which it was mark with duplicate does not give this answer.